# Pasar una imagen de un fragmento a otro

Tags: java, android

Tengo una aplicacion que en un fragmento toma fotos con la camara o la carga desde la galeria, hasta ahi todo bien, llega a la camara y tambien me deja seleccionar la foto de la galeria.
El problema es que quiero que muestre seguidamente la foto tomada/imagen seleccionada en otro fragmento con un par de botones
En resumen, quisiera pasar la foto como parametro a otro fragmento, lei por ahi que se puede con `bundle`, pero me es muy confuso como hacerlo y dónde.

Dejo el codigo que llama a la camara, a la galeria, y dónde guardo la imagen

```
private void navigateToCamera() {
    Intent nativeCameraIntent = new Intent().setClass(getActivity(), NativeCameraActivity.class);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(nativeCameraIntent, RESULT_LOAD_PHOTO);
}

public void loadImageFromGallery() {
    // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
    Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    // Start the Intent
    startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);

}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();

            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.faceImg);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
           imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_PHOTO && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.faceImg);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(data.getStringExtra("imageUri")));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.no_photo_selected, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Muestra el codigo de como cargas el Fragmento para poder dar una respuesta completa.

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de tus dos fragmentos

Answer (score 0):

La comunicación directa entre fragmentos no se recomienda. Un fragmento no debe conocer nunca a otro fragmento, y menos dar por supuesta su existencia. En todo caso, que el fragmentoA envíe la imagen al MainActivity y que el MainActivity lo envíe al fragmentoB.
Esto lo puedes conseguir de la siguiente forma:

1- Creas una interfaz de comunicación entre el fragmento y la actividad, que deberá ser implementada por ésta última. Asigna dicha interfaz en el onAttach del fragmento.

```
public static class FragmentoA extends Fragment {
    Callback listener;

    ....

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            // Establece la actividad como objeto listener.
            listener = (Callback) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // La actividad no implementa la interfaz.
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + 
                " debe implementar la interfaz Callback del fragmento");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        listener = null;
    }

    ...
    // La actividad que contiene el fragmento debe implementar esta interfaz.
    public interface Callback {
        public void onEnvioImagen(Bitmap imagen);
    }
    ...
}
```

2- En este mismo fragmentoA, **cuando recibas la imagen**, llama al método de la interfaz que provocará que el MainActivity se haga cargo:

```
listener.onEnvioImagen(tuImagen);
```

3- Implementa la interfaz Callback en la actividad y sobreescribe el metodo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentoA.Callback  {
 public void onEnvioImagen(Bitmap imagen){
    //Codigo para crear el nuevo fragmento y envíale la imagen
    FragmentUtils.replaceFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.fragmentLayout_de_main,
                    FragmentoB.newInstance(imagen), TAG_MAIN_FRAGMENT);
 }
}
```